# Where to put my application logic when using Entity Framework and MVVM

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm, architecture

In the last days I spent a lot of time creating the architecture for my program, but still have a problem with it. At the moment it looks like this:

- **DataLayer:** Here my context class which derived from DbContext and the mapper classes which derived from EntityTypeConfiguration like *JobMap* for the Domain objects reside
- **DomainLayer:** Here my domain/business objects like *Job* or *Schedule* reside.
- **Presentation Layer:** Here I have the *ViewModel and *View classes (I use WPF for the views)

Now to my question: I want to build a scheduling application with some optimization abilities (it is a single user and single pc application so no further decoupling like web application is needed). But I have the problem that I don't know where this application fits into this architecture?

Considering the following use case: The user clicks a button "Start" on the View which calls the ViewModel which redirects to my scheduling/optimization application. This app then gets all the new jobs from the database and creates/updates the current schedule. The ViewModel should then update the old schedule with the new created one. Finally the View shows the generated schedule to the user.
In this case my ViewModel knows about my application (because it calls it) and about my domain/business objects (because my app will deliver e.g. a *Schedule* domain object, which the ViewModel encapsulates).

Is this a correct usage of the EF, MVVM and my application?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, you'll want to identify which pieces of your application go where, and that's fairly easy to do.  Essentially, you have to ask yourself: Does this method or class help define my domain.  If the answer is yes, you put it in the domain layer, and if not, you'll put it in presentation.

Here's how you'd look at it in your example:

- Your Presentation layer (PL) receives a message via the start
  button.
- The PL calls the Domain and tells it to generate a schedule.  This call is probably to a domain service.
- Your domain service is then in charge of populating the Job domain objects, creating a new Schedule domain object (or modifying an existing one), and returning the Schedule domain object.
- Your PL then simply displays the returned Schedule.

This might be different if you just wanted to obtain an existing Schedule object.  Instead of calling a domain service, you would ask a domain repository to get the existing schedule.  The repository would be the way of encapsulating or otherwise obscuring the data layer from your PL and from your Domain.

Now, what you DON'T want to do:

- Do not get the list of jobs in your PL, and then use that list of jobs to create the  schedule in the controller of your MVVM.  This would be business logic that defines your domain.
- If Schedules are commonly generated from Jobs, regardless of whether it's called from MVVM or a PHP site, then don't add complexity in your PL and Domain Layer by forcing the PL to first get the jobs and pass them back into the Domain for a Schedule to be generated. The fact that those two concepts are tied to each other means that the relationship helps define your domain, and thus belongs in your domain layer.  An exception might be when both the jobs and the schedule to be modified both rely on context from the front end (user input), but even this isn't always an exception.
- Do not pass in VMs to your domain.  Let your controller filter out the data and determine what needs to be sent to which domain part.

It's really hard to give a precise detail of what you should place where because only you would have a clear view of what defines your domain, but here's essentially how I break it down:

**Could I change/replace this without affecting how my business/domain works?**

If the answer is yes, it does not belong in your domain.  Example:  You could replace your entire MVVM front-end to flat PHP or ASPX, and even though it'd be a lot of work and a huge pain, you could to do it without affecting how the rest of the business operates.